# How to render not transparent emojis in GGPLOT in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, emoji

I am trying to show some emojis in my plots in rmarkdown using the library emo:
https://github.com/hadley/emo

Using inline code like `r emo::ji('poo')` does render well, and the emoji is complete with colors, but when using it for the `ylab` for my plots, it is rendered transparent, only showing the edges. Note that I am using `UTF-8`.

Here is the actual output of the inline code I showed you before:

[image]

And the output of the emoji in the plot:

[image]